# add webparts inside page layout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I've been tearing my hear out with this one today.

I've created a new page layout and inserted an empty web part zone inside it,
now when i add any web part to the web part zone using share point designer, web parts don't appear when i view the page, and when i edit the page only an empty web part zone shows.

I've created a new page layout and inserted an empty web part zone inside it,
now when i add any web part to the web part zone using share point designer, web parts don't appear when i view the page, and when i edit the page only an empty web part zone shows.

in short words, How can i add web parts to a page layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you intend to have a zone available to add webparts using each page's edit mode, add a webpart zone to your page layout.

if you want fixed webparts, add them outside the webpartzone, as standalone.

sharepoint designer is buggy on accomplishing webpart drag and drops and often the insert webpart/webpartzone will be greyed out, but if you go to design view and back (sp2010) the options become available again

my advice is use code view if you are on 2010 and make sure your edited page layout is the one actually assigned to your test page